# Using preg_match to find which group is being replaced by preg_replace in php

Tags: php, preg-match

I am using preg_replace to find 2 corresponding words and then switching their places. I want to check that if the two corresponding words are:

```
<span style="color: green;"> </span>,
```

then the while loop should not work. I have tried many patterns but can't write the correct one. The one that I have used is:

```
if(!preg_match ('~<span style="color: green;"></span>~', $myinput))
```

but it is not working in the way I want. You can view my complete code here in this link: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf21f671ef7fcaaabad063fe235383550df0a59e

Comment: Start by the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php and possibly showing us what `$myinput` is.

Comment: If your string is `$myinput = "<span style="color: green;"> </span>,";`, then you're not using that function correctly `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'color' (T_STRING)...` - Your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, this if from where I studied, but still the description is not quite clear

Comment: Yes, the mentioned are the 2 corresponding strings that I want to find

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, is the space you have in

```
<span style="color: green;"> </span>,
                            ^
```

and your pattern doesn't contain it.

```
if(!preg_match ('~<span style="color: green;"></span>~', $myinput))
```

which you would need to add it in:

```
if(!preg_match ('~<span style="color: green;"> </span>~', $myinput))
```

Assuming:

```
$myinput = '<span style="color: green;"> </span>,';
```

My test code and using `if(preg_match` instead of `if(!preg_match`:

```
<?php 

$myinput = '<span style="color: green;"> </span>,';

if(preg_match ('~<span style="color: green;"> </span>~', $myinput))
{
   echo "Found.";
}

else{
   echo "Not found.";
}
```

Comment: @MariumMalik then, what you may need to do is reverse your preg_match with `if(preg_match` instead of `if(!preg_match`. My test proved successful when using that.

Comment: @MariumMalik Ok hold on, let me see what I can do with the code you left in your link.

Comment: Okay. Check this link, not the previous one. Previous one was the wrong one that I mentioned. Thanks

Comment: I have got it worked. I have used \s* in between as there were spaces in between.

Comment: @MariumMalik Funny, I had a feeling about using that earlier and was working on line of code for it. Oh well, you got your solution, *cheers*

Comment: @MariumMalik You know that Stack lets you post your own answer. You could post the actual code that you used in order to provide yourself with the solution and for future readers to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it worked. I have used \s* in between the opening and closing tag of span as there were spaces in between.

Comment: in between where exactly? this doesn't really show us where you put that in.